# Question on Union - split to multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

All,

I have 2 tables as below.

Table 1

```
Row ID  LabID   TMS
1234    DA      65.2
```

Table2

```
RowID   LabID    Waterpct
4567     AC        8.2

Select
RowID, LabID, TMS
from table1
 UNION ALL
RowID,LabID,Waterpct
from table2
```

I want the output like below

```
RowID, LabID, TMS, Waterpct
1234   DA     65.2
4567   AC             8.2
```

But my union query above did not bring the expected format.
Can some one please advice?
Appreciate your help.

Thanks,
John

Answer (score 0):

So, put the data in the columns you want:

```
Select RowID, LabID, TMS, NULL as Waterpct
from table1
union all
select RowID, LabID, NULL, Waterpct
from table2;
```